# Best way to send few string fields in QR code

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

I am working on a scenario similar to web usage of WhatsApp. I want to scan a QR code on browser from inside mobile app and authenticate the user to login.

What would be the best way to send the authentication message in QR code? I am planning to use `JSON` as I need to send few string fields? Also, I plan to do base 64 encoding and decoding. Is it a good way to do it? Does anyone know how WhatsApp is doing it?

Comment: This my be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350286/mechanism-behind-qr-code-scanning-of-whatsapp-webapp

Comment: This question is too broad. Do you know how to create the QR? Do you ask about how to encode the information? Or are you asking about what information to include into the QR? In stackoverflow is better to ask one thing each time and after you have tried doing it so you have some specific problem.

Comment: A brief info: In my opinion you should use a token for the information (never show a QR with the real data as every body near can scan it). About encoding, use whatever is less characters (a token is already a string so don't use any encoding). About WhatsApp, scan their code with a generic QR scanner to see what information it has.