# WhatsApp Web parameters

Tags: android, https, wireshark, whatsapp, burp

I am trying to analyse what is being exchanged between an Android device and browser during WhatsApp Web initialization (when scanning the QR code).

The mechanism has being described in a post here: [Mechanism behind QR code scanning of WhatsApp web/desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350286/mechanism-behind-qr-code-scanning-of-whatsapp-webapp#)

The thing is I am unable to see the traffic from Android device once the QR code is scanned. Using tpacketcapture all looks encrypted.

I also tried using Burp suite with its cert in the device to mimic MITM to see https traffic but I can't see any WhatsApp traffic.

WhatsApp doesn't use HTTPS?

Any idea how to analyse the parameters exchanged during WhatsApp Web session of it is even possible.

Comment: it uses WebSockets and not HTTPS